# how to distribute array items organized as a series of tree branches?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to expand/distribute an array such as:

```js
[
  ["a", "b"],
  [
    ["c", "d"],
    ["e", "f", "g"]
  ],
  [
    ["h", "i"],
    ["j"],
    ["k", "l"],
    ["m"],
    ["n", "o", "p"]
  ]
]
```

so that it becomes:

```json
["ach", "aci", "adj", "bek", "bel", "bfm", "bgn", "bgo","bgp"]
```

That is, each item in the top level array is distributed on the previous item's sub-array.
For the example above, the expansion would follow these steps:

- First stage :

  - ["c", "d"] is distributed on "a", resulting in ["ac", "ad"]
  - ["e", "f", "g"] is distributed on "b", resulting in ["be", "bf", "bg"]
- Second stage :

  - ["h", "i"] is distributed on "ac", resulting in ["ach", "aci"]
  - ["j"] is distributed on "ad", resulting in ["adj"]
  - ["k", "l"] is distributed on "be", resulting in ["bek", "bel"]
  - ["m"] is distributed on "bf", resulting in ["bfm"]
  - ["n", "o", "p"] is distributed on "bg", resulting in ["bgn", "bgo","bgp"]

The overall process resulting : ["ach", "aci", "adj", "bek", "bel", "bfm", "bgn", "bgo","bgp"]
But I'm lost in recursion here...
Can someone help ?

I tried with the following javascript function but this fails:

```
function distributeArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  }

  const subResults = distributeArray(arr.slice(1));
  const result = [];

  for (const item of arr[0]) {
    for (const subResult of subResults) {
      result.push(item + subResult);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const inputArray = [["a", "b"], [["c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g"]], [["h", "i"], ["j"], ["k", "l"], ["m"], ["n", "o", "p"]]];

var outputArray = distributeArray(inputArray);
console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion. Here's how you can do it instead:

```js
function distributeArray(inputs) {
  let result = inputs[0]

  for (let inputIndex = 1; inputIndex < inputs.length; inputIndex++) {
    const input = inputs[inputIndex]

    if (input.length !== result.length) {
      throw new Error(`Expected to see ${result.length} values in the input at index ${inputIndex}, but instead saw ${input.length}: ${JSON.stringify(input)}`)
    }

    const resultNew = []

    for (let inputInnerIndex = 0; inputInnerIndex < input.length; inputInnerIndex++) {
      const stringExisting = result[inputInnerIndex]
      const inputArray = input[inputInnerIndex]
      const inputArrayMerged = inputArray.map((string) => stringExisting + string)
      resultNew.push(...inputArrayMerged)
    }

    result = resultNew
  }

  return result
}


const distributed = distributeArray([
  ["a", "b"],
  [
    ["c", "d"],
    ["e", "f", "g"],
  ],
  [
    ["h", "i"],
    ["j"],
    ["k", "l"],
    ["m"],
    ["n", "o", "p"],
  ],
])

console.log(distributed)
```

Here's the same code with some explanatory comments. I hope they aren't too confusing!

```
function distributeArray(inputs) {
  let result = inputs[0]
  // starts as ["a", "b"]

  // 1, 2
  for (let inputIndex = 1; inputIndex < inputs.length; inputIndex++) {
    const input = inputs[inputIndex]
    // 1: [["c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g"]]
    // 2: [["h", "i"], ["j"], ["k", "l"], ["m"], ["n", "o", "p"]]

    if (input.length !== result.length) {
      throw new Error(`Expected to see ${result.length} values in the input at index ${inputIndex}, but instead saw ${input.length}: ${JSON.stringify(input)}`)
    }

    const resultNew = []

    // 1: 0, 1
    // 2: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    for (let inputInnerIndex = 0; inputInnerIndex < input.length; inputInnerIndex++) {
      const stringExisting = result[inputInnerIndex]
      // 1: 0: "a"
      // 1: 1: "b"
      // 2: 0: "ac"
      // 2: 1: "ad"
      // 2: 2: "be"
      // 2: 3: "bf"
      // 2: 4: "bg"

      const inputArray = input[inputInnerIndex]
      // 1: 0: ["c", "d"]
      // 1: 1: ["e", "f", "g"]
      // 2: 0: ["h", "i"]
      // 2: 1: ["j"]
      // 2: 2: ["k", "l"]
      // 2: 3: ["m"]
      // 2: 4: ["n", "o", "p"]

      const inputArrayMerged = inputArray.map((string) => stringExisting + string)
      // 1: 0: ["ac", "ad"]
      // 1: 1: ["be", "bf", "bg"]
      // 2: 0: ["ach", "aci"]
      // 2: 1: ["adj"]
      // 2: 2: ["bek", "bel"]
      // 2: 3: ["bfm"]
      // 2: 4: ["bgn", "bgo", "bgp"]

      resultNew.push(...inputArrayMerged)
      // 1: 0: [] + ["ac", "ad"]
      // 1: 1: ["ac", "ad"] + ["be", "bf", "bg"]
      // 2: 0: [] + ["ach", "aci"]
      // 2: 1: ["ach", "aci"] + ["adj"]
      // 2: 2: ["ach", "aci", "adj"] + ["bek", "bel"]
      // 2: 3: ["ach", "aci", "adj", "bek", "bel"] + ["bfm"]
      // 2: 4: ["ach", "aci", "adj", "bek", "bel", "bfm"] + ["bgn", "bgo", "bgp"]
    }

    result = resultNew
  }

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive style with an array for the offsets of the nested arrays.

```js
const
    combine = (data, index = 0, offsets = [0]) => {
        offsets[index + 1] ??= 0;
        
        if (index >= data.length) return [''];
        
        return (index ? data[index][offsets[index]] : data[index]).flatMap(a => {
            const r = combine(data, index + 1, offsets).map(b => a + b);
            offsets[index + 1]++;
            return r;
        });
    },
    data = [["a", "b"], [["c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g"]], [["h", "i"], ["j"], ["k", "l"], ["m"], ["n", "o", "p"]]],
    result = combine(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```